# How to reset ruby class accessors between requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scoping, settingslogic

I'm working on ecommerce solution, which provides few different shops within a single rails application.

There I have a class to hold shop-specific settings.

```
# models/shop.rb
class Shop < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/shop.yml"

  def self.init!(shop)
    namespace shop.to_s
    load!
  end

end
```

Shop::init! loads a specified section from config file

Here is yml file just in case:

```
# config/shop.yml
shop_1:
  shop_name: Shop 1
shop_2:
  shop_name: Shop 2
```

I match requested shop by domain name in application controller.

```
# controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_shop

  protected

  def set_shop
    Shop.init! if request.domain.match(/^.*shop1\.com$/)
      :shop_1
    elsif request.domain.match(/^.*shop2\.com$/)
      :shop_2
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that Shop somehow keeps settings for the first requested shop between requests.
For example:

shop1.com

```
Shop.shop_name # => Shop 1
```

shop2.com

```
Shop.shop_name # => Shop 1
```

And it keeps initial settings until I make some change to either application_controller.rb or shop.rb. (I think it's a first key to the answer)

What I know is that Settingslogic defines attr_accessor for each option in shop.yml (only when first called though). But why they still work after reloading (I work in development environment with cache_classes = false)

When I do that way:

```
# models/shop.rb
class Shop < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/shop.yml"
  namespace  "shop_#{Random.rand(1..2)}"
  load!
end
```

it works as expected - it loads appropriate settings everytime. But I can't set shop name by domain on this stage. Also I'm not able to test different shops when I can't specify shop_name from the outside. So I need to have a method.

I tried `class_eval`

```
def self.init!(shop)
  class_eval do
    namespace shop.to_s
    load!
  end
end
```

but it didn't help. I feel a lack of knowledge on scoping here.
Do you have ideas what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have many shops, why are you using a singleton `Shop` instead of multiple `Shop` instances?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall because app doesn't know that there are other shops. It just needs to access to shop-specific settings like it was a regular Settings model which is subclass of Settingslogic.
The only difference is that I load different sections of settings file depending on `request.domain`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thank you. When I realized what was the problem, your answer helped me realize that I need a new instance of Shop per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason that class attributes shouldn't be preserved until they are next updated.

In development mode in a rails app, your code is reloaded when it has changed, which will have the side effect of resetting those class variables, but you don't want to rely on that.

What your before filter should be doing is setting a @current_shop instance variable that contains the shop to use for the current request.

Comment: Yes, @current_shop would be ok if I needed only shop name. I just simplified my config file. 
There are other options that should be accessible in different places of application:

`Shop.layout` - in controllers or views

`Shop.tax` - in models

`Shop.email.general` - in mailers

etc.

Comment: I was writing a second comment regard class caching and realized that the whole approach is wrong and probably my question too. Whether I call `load!` directly in the class or I wrap it in the method `init!` it won't work as I expected in production. Thanks for answer.

Comment: You could use thread locals to have a Shop.current method that you could use anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution on how to stick to initial plan mentioned in question, but to not have "class caching" problem.

It is based on the answer to [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310711/accessing-object-everywhere-in-rails-app) on this topic.

Anyway here is new Shop.rb

```
class Shop < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/shop.yml"
  load!

  def self.current=(shop)
    Thread.current[:current_shop] = shop.to_sym
  end

  def self.current
    self.send(Thread.current[:current_shop])
  end
end
```

I decided to load all sections of shop.yml and access them through Shop::current which forwards the call to appropriate section.

So I can use `Shop.current.name` and `Shop.current.tax` anywhere and it corresponds to the shop which was set in applicationController or spec_helper.