# Accessing object everywhere in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables

I know this is 1001st question about global objects, but I think my situation is slightly different.

I'm working on ecommerce solution, which provides few different shops within a single rails application.

There is a class Shop which provides shop-specific logic and options. For example:

`@shop.tax` should be accessible in models. Tax can differ depend on shop. eg 9%, 18%.

`@shop.name` and `@shop.layout` should be accessible in controllers and views.

`@shop.email.general` for mailers.

I need to be able to create an instance of Shop in application controller and somehow pass it to the all application parts.

```
# controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_shop

  protected

  def set_shop
    requested_shop = if request.domain.match(/^.*shop1\.com$/)
      :shop_1
    elsif request.domain.match(/^.*shop2\.com$/)
      :shop_2
    end
    @shop = Shop.new(requested_shop)
  end
end
```

I know that request-based logic should not be used in models, but I really need shop options there. In tests I could mock this "global" object like that `Shop.new(:test_shop)` in spec_helper.

Is global variable my only choice? I've never used them.

I tried to use Settingslogic gem, but it defines attr_accessors for shop-specific options, and they persist between requests, which is not what I need.

Comment: looks fine to me.. whats broken?

Comment: if `Shop` is a model then it should already be accessible in all parts of your application: models, views, controllers, mailers

Comment: @BenjaminSullivan Yes, `Shop` is accessible, but I need `@shop` which I defined in `ApplicationController`. 

For eaxample I need to calculate tax for the current shop in `Order` model. I could create another instance of `Shop`, but I don't have access to request.

Comment: @AJcodez yes, works fine. Just trying to figure out how to access `@shop` from other models.

Comment: Ok so you have `@shop`. It's available in your controller actions and your views. Where else do you need to access it?

Comment: @BenjaminSullivan at least in `Order` and `Cart` models to calculate the tax. In all the mailers to set `:from => @shop.email`. Also I will need it in ActiveRecord concerns which I mixin to some of my models. If I can pass @shop to models via arguments, pass it to concerns would be a little tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be something like

```
class Shop
  def self.current=(shop)
    Thread.current[:current_shop] = shop
  end

  def self.current
    Thread.current[:current_shop]
  end
end
```

Which allows you to maintain a separate current shop for each request.

The alternative is to pass the current shop around. It may seem tedious at first but can ultimately be simpler to reason about than global or pseudo global  behaviour

Comment: Thanks for answer. I like first option, because `Shop` is such a fundamental thing in this application that passing it around seems overwhelming. Do you think this approach would work fine in Rails4 with threadsafe! on?

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store as a drop-in replacement to Thread.current.. it essentially 'scopes' the variable to the lifetime of the request, so that subsequent requests that are unrelated won't see left-overs from previous requests.